# Parameterize the globalization tag in web.config in an ASP.NET application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, globalization

I am working on an application in which user has to enter the country he/she belongs to.

We want this to implement culture specific number formatting every time a user enter his/her country.
Can we pass the country parameter to the globalization tag in web.config to make the application behave in accordance to the user's selected country?

```
<globalization uiCulture="CountryParam"  culture="CountryParam" />
```

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) which boils down to setting `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` and `CurrentUICulture`...

Comment: I have tried to apply a switch case in "InitializeCulture.cs",but still because     Thread.CurrentThread.InstalledCulture = "en-US"

Comment: Show us your code by adding it to the question.

Comment: I have tried to apply a switch case in "InitializeCulture.cs",but still because CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture = "en-US",it doesn't work properly and number formatting doesn't happen property.I mean you can't save 2,00 as 2.00  according to "nl-NL".

Comment: I have shown the code in the question "<globalization uiCulture="CountryParam"  culture="CountryParam" />",can we parameterize the globalization tag.

Comment: In your comments you state you tried a switch in InitializeCulture obviusly to achieve something that didn't work and then you mention InstalledCulture which has really nothing to do with the UICulture hence my request to add that specific code you tried in InitializeCulture that didn't work for you to be added to your question because the solution is in that method.

Comment: Actually CultureInfo.InstalledCulture is a read-only property in MetaData,so because of this property,globalization could not be achieved. For example for "Netherlands" user the numbers are displayed in US format i.e 1,000,000.00 and not 1.000.000,00. I can't post the code right now.Would have to get some approvals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IN Asp.Net and/or MVC you just have to set `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` and `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` to the culture of the user

If you do so, all formatting should be done based on this culture per default.

Otherwise you would have to run string.Format with the specific culture provided by you in all places you do string formatting, using [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/1ksz8yb7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)...

As you can see in the documentation of string.Format, without defining a specific culture, it will use `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`

[Taken from here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Format_Culture)

> Generally, objects in the argument list are converted to their string representations by using the conventions of the current culture, which is returned by the CultureInfo.CurrentCulture property. You can control this behavior by calling the Format(IFormatProvider, String, Object[]) overload. This overload's provider parameter is an IFormatProvider implementation that supplies custom and culture-specific formatting information that is used to moderate the formatting process.

Comment: Would be difficult to use String.Format every where as the application has integers and decimals which are use in calculations.Is there no way we can add parameter to the globalization tag and completely override the installed US culture.

Comment: @Shivam657 This is exactly what `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` / UICulture is meant for ;) Just set it and you don't have to set it in all places...
But of course you have to format your output, so if you output your decimal somewhere on the page, you have to use some formatting right? Usually this is done automatically. If you just output a decimal, most likely the ToString method will be invoked internally... and this one also uses the CurrentCulture set on the current thread as default...

Comment: Ya will try and do that.But is it possible to parameterize the globalization tag in web.config?